# Characteristic method for solving a linear PDE $xyz_x-x^2z_y=-yz$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Find the solution of the linear PDE
>   $$xyz_x-x^2z_y=-yz$$

**Chacteristic equations:**

$$\frac{dx}{xy}=\frac{dy}{-x^2}=\frac{dz}{-y}$$

from here, I found the characteristic $x^2+y^2=c_1$ and $lnx+z=c_2$.

since $c_2=f(c_1)$, we have $lnx+z=f(x^2+y^2)$ and solution is $z=f(x^2+y^2)-lnx$.

It is right?
if it is wrong, where am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't be $\dfrac{dz}{-yz}$.?

Comment: We can write the term for quasi linear. Can't we write it for linear pde? Why?

Comment: Let $f\equiv t^2$. Is your answer valid? check

Comment: It's not valid.  Why doesn't the method work?

Comment: Write it again with true Characteristic equations

Comment: I don't know. Pls help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{xy}=\frac{dy}{-x^2}=\frac{dz}{-yz}$$
then with $\dfrac{dx}{xy}=\dfrac{dy}{-x^2}$ we find $x^2+y^2=C_1$ and with $\dfrac{dx}{xy}=\dfrac{dz}{-yz}$ we have $xz=C_2$ thus
$$z=\frac{f(x^2+y^2)}{x}$$